# How to check types of key and value if Object instanceof HashMap?

Tags: java, object, unchecked-cast

I have a method that accepts an Object. In one use case, the method accepts a `HashMap<String, String>` and sets each value to the property of the corresponding key name.

```
public void addHelper(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof HashMap) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) object;
        this.foo = hashMap.get("foo");
        this.bar = hashMap.get("bar");
    }
}
```

This class adheres to a particular interface, so adding setters for those properties is not an option.

My question is, how can I check the type cast here?

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) object;
```

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the answer from @drobert, here is my updated code:

```
public void addHelper(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Map) {
        Map map = (Map) object;
        if (map.containsKey("foo")) this.foo = map.get("foo").toString();
        if (map.containsKey("bar")) this.bar = map.get("bar").toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, how to remove unchecked cast warning you get?

Comment: You can use if (obj instanceof String) {
//your code
}

Comment: @Sarma The object is a `HashMap<String,String>` not `String`

Comment: U can type cast HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) object;It will work with warnings.

Comment: This solution simplifies a bit, but doesn't solve a problem of `instanceof Map<smth>` in Java. Java has lack of this functionality.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't. Due to type erasure, reflection will show you have an instance of HashMap, but the  types are dropped at runtime. Effectively, you have HashMap< Object,Object >.

That said, you still have some options, and some advice I'd suggest you take. Among them:

- Check to see if it's an instance of 'Map' rather than 'HashMap'. It will make your API much more flexible since you most likely only care that you have rapid access by key rather than any particular impementation
- Take advantage of java.util.Map's api which defines 'containsKey(Object)' and 'get(Object)', so you can still use mapInst.get("stringKey") safely, even without having to cast.
- You can't ensure all values are strings, but you can take advantage of java.lang.Object's toString() method and obtain a String for each value regardless.

In short: treat this like any Map, and attempt to access the keys as Strings even without the cast, and attempt to utilize each value as a String by doing a null check then calling .toString() and you'll have a much safer implementation.

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that the original routine is exactly equivalent to coding

```
public void addHelper(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof HashMap) {
        HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) object;
        this.foo = (String)(hashMap.get("foo"));
        this.bar = (String)(hashMap.get("bar"));
    }
}
```

The explicit `(HashMap)` cast cannot possibly throw an error, since it's guarded by the `instanceof`.  The implicitly-supplied `(String)` casts will only throw an error if the values returned from the HashMap are not Strings (or nulls).

(By "exactly equivalent to" I mean that the same bytecode is produced.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use try-catch, where you call `addHelper(Object)` method. This will ensure your correct type of `HashMap`.

```
      try{
        addHelper(hashMap);
        }
        catch(ClassCastException ex){
            System.out.println("Is not desired hashmap");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try{
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) object;
    this.foo = hashMap.get("foo");
    this.bar = hashMap.get("bar");
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        System.err.log("Object is not a hashmap");
    }
```

Now, you know the object is of the correct type - even a custom abstract class or otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried with your code? ClassCastExp throw when you call addHelper method.

Comment: this is a generic solution showing how the type handling works, its trivial to put it in addHelper

Comment: This is not generic solution. Please, run your code, than you will see where exception is thrown.

Comment: So where will the exception be thrown, and why?

Comment: it gets thrown on a mismatch of method to object/calling map methods on a non-map object

Comment: It will get thrown due to the hidden cast generated on the results of hashMap.get, as it's cast from Object to String.  If indeed the result is not a String.  If the result is a String then no exception is thrown.  The cast to HashMap will throw an error only if "object" is not a HashMap at all, and that is probably better checked with `instanceof` rather than waiting for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Java 14 introduced support for pattern matching (Preview) for the instanceof operator.
And from java 16 as full support [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394).
Now you can achieve this by doing that like this:

```
if (object instanceof Map myMap
    && myMap.get("foo") instanceof String myFoo
    && myMap.get("bar") instanceof String myBar) {

    this.foo = myFoo;
    this.bar = myBar;
}
```

Some notes:

- If your map declared as Map<String, String> then there no need to check the second check for "bar", on this example i did it only to match the question asked.
- If your map declared as Map<String, Object> then it's better to check all the options as i did in my example.
- If for some reason you don't have the key for one of the values in the map but the values are from the same type!

you can do this:

```
if (result instanceof Map myMap
    && !myMap.isEmpty()
    && myMap.values().stream().findFirst().get() instanceof String value) { // or any other type you need to check... 
 //do something...
}
```

Hope this will help someone in the future...